# Problemas con scroll al cargar pagina

Tags: scroll

Buenas noches. Tengo un inconveniente con mi pagina. Al cargarla o recargarla el scroll se va al final de la página, lo normal es que se mantenga arriba. Alguien le ha sucedido algo similar o podrian ayudarme a darme una solución? Utilizo bootstrap.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenid@ te sugiero realices primeramente el [tour] y posteriormente leas [ask] para obtener información y recomendaciones para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

En el onload de tu página puedes hacer que el scroll se mantenga arriba.

Primero guardas el scroll nada más entrar en tu página usando lo siguiente:
    `var tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();`

Esto puedes almacenarlo en una variable global o algo similar.
Entonces al cargar o recargar la página puedes volver a recuperar la variable y modificar la posición del scroll.
`$(window).scrollTop(tempScrollTop);`

El lenguaje de los ejemplos es Jquery, un saludo!